# Algorithm for finding unique members of array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I need to write a simple algorithm to:

1. Find sort out unique members of an array
2. Put those members to another array
3. Count number of unique members

Here's an example:

```
char array1[103] = {'V', 'U', 'A', 'A', 'U', 'U', 'A', 'A', 'V', 'U', 'A', 'V', 'V', 'U', 'U'};
char array2[10]; //Empty
//Output should be:
3
V U A
```

I need to write it in c++, but pseuodo code would be also great. I can write code by myself I only need to get idea of this algorithm.

Comment: Here's an advice, to find the algorithm, you have to think about it. Try to do what you were asked to do on paper, write each step on how to do that and then you'll have your pseudo code.

Comment: I don't need to do this task automaticaly I need to undestand an Idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an empty `std::unordered_set` object. A set is a collection that has only holds unique elements.
2. Loop through the input array, adding the elements to the set.
3. When done, copy the elements of the set into the output array.

Comment: The `unordered_set` makes it unique, since it doesn't store duplicates.

Comment: Look at his example output. He means to remove all the duplicates.

Comment: Are we here to critique people's questioning style or help them with programming?

Comment: And "unique" is commonly used to describe that operation. PHP has `array_unique`, C++ has `std::unique`.

Comment: Describing clearly what needs to be done is the first and most important step of programming. If only people would be able to express things clearly... So, @Barmar, don't scold me!

Answer (score 0):

Following may help:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char array1[103] = {'V', 'U', 'A', 'A', 'U', 'U', 'A', 'A', 'V', 'U', 'A', 'V', 'V', 'U', 'U'};
    char array2[10]; //Empty
    int size = strlen(array1); // get the used size of the array

    std::sort(std::begin(array1), array1 + size);
    auto it = std::unique(std::begin(array1), array1 + size);
    size = it - std::begin(array1);
    assert(size < 10);
    std::copy(std::begin(array1), it, std::begin(array2));
    std::cout << size << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
        std::cout << array2[i] << " ";
    }
    // Output is:
    //3
    //A U V
    return 0;
}
```